# The correlation between bufferedwrite and n characters

Tags: java

```java
public class SieveOfEratosthenes_re {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int count = 0;

        boolean[] arr = new boolean[N+1];
        for(int i=2; i<=N; i++){
            if(count==K){
                break;
            }
            for(int j=i; j<=N; j+=i){
                if(arr[j]==false){
                    arr[j] = true;
                    count++;
                }
                if(count==K){
                    bw.write(j + "\n"); // I don't know this part
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

If n is added to the bufferedwrite, it is output from the terminal, and if n is not added, it is not output.
What's the reason?

Answer (score 4):

You apparently want to know what this line does:

```
  bw.write(j + "\n");
```

The first thing that happens is that `j + "\n"` is evaluated.  Since one of the operands is a string, that `+` is a string concatenation (see [JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)).  The value of the other operand is converted to a `String` *as if* you called `new String(int)` on it (see [JLS 5.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)).  That renders it in decimal format.

For example, if `j` was 42, the result of that will be a string equivalent to `"42\n"`; i.e. 3 characters.

Then `Writer.write(String)` is used to output the string which just writes the characters of the string (see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String))

---

Your self answer says:

> `Bufferedwrite` receives characters, so if you type int, it outputs an empty value.

It it hard to understand exactly what you mean, but if you are saying `BufferedWriter.write(int)` outputs an "empty value", that is incorrect.  The `Writer.write(int)` method interprets the `int` as a Unicode codepoint and outputs that ... according to the encoding of the output stream you are writing to.

That is NEVER an empty value.

It *might* be a non-printing character (e.g. an ASCII control character), but even those are not empty.  There will be something in the output stream.